# Where do I go from the Red box?

Tags: dnd-4e, experience-points

Me and my group just finished the essentials red box, and are looking at moving to the full 4e game. I'm doing some preliminary reading of the books and one thing is confusing me a little.

The characters from the red box are up to level 2 now, and I don't know where I'd find the information on what EXP they level up at. Furthering that, whilst I've found (in the PHB) how many hit points a class would gain at a certain level, I can't find where it says what amount should be added to other attributes, like perception, dexterity, etc.

Many on forums say move to Heroes of Forgotten Kingdoms, but the same character classes (Cleric, Warrior, etc.) don't reappear in that book - it just adds some new ones.

Which book would I find this information in? Or am I just missing it?

TL;DR: Where do I find attribute increases for classes by level & where do I find leveling up EXP?

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Comment: The classes: Knight, Slayer, Thief, Warpriest, and Mage are the continuation of the Red Box classes, to some degree. You'll still need to do some reworking to get them to be quite right.

Comment: Attributes don't increase every level. At every level ending in 4 or 8 characters can add 1 to any two attributes of their choice. At levels 11 & 21 all attributes go up by 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The information that you seek is available in the following places:

- Heroes of the Fallen Land
- Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdom
- Players Handbook 1 (may be in the rest of them, not sure).
- The Rules Compendium
- The DDI online compendium and character builder.

As far as where to go post redbox, I'd like to present two options.

1. Buy Heroes of the Forgotten Kingdom. This gives you the continuation for the classes that you characters are currently playing (Knight/Slayer - Fighter, Thief - Rogue, Mage - Wizard, Warpriest - Cleric). You might also have to pick up Heroes of the Fallen Lands to get all of them, not 100% sure. Anyways, you can pick up those books, you'll have to do a touch of recreating your characters, but the transfer should be roughly equivalent. This contains all of the information you need to level them up and whatnot. What you'll be missing if you *only* purchase these two books are full rules summaries (contained in teh Rule Compendium, which I highly recommend regardless of what else you do). And DM information (available in the DM Kit, which is another great purchase). You also don't get any more pre-made adventures (either Monter Vault has adventures that should allow you to pick up right from where you left off in the same world. This is a great source of tokens and the first monster vault's adventure is quite good, haven't played through the other one).
2. Get a DDI subscription. This gives you access to the online character builder, literally the easiest way to build a character. The whole process is guided and the rules are enforced through the construction of the character. You have access to all classes ever and all races and feats and whatnot. You *also* get access to the online compendium which contains, basically, every monster, every item and every rule for the entire game. In addition you get access to the entire catalog of 4e related Dungeon and Dragon magazine issues which have literally a hundred or so adventures published in them.

I've had a DDI subscription for a touch over 2 years now and it's been invaluable. As new 4e players it was helpful to find the rules quickly and easily and to figure out how to build characters. Now as relatively experienced player it's a great help when I'm trying to solve and optimization puzzle, answering a question here or doing just about anything related to the game.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know, thanks a lot, I think I'm gonna go ahead and get a DDI subscription! :D

Comment: Also DDI Gives you the monster builder (great for making custom monsters) and encounter builder (mostly worthless, but it helps you match XP Budget to party size and level).