# How to continue d&d after the redbox

Tags: dnd-4e

I had a question. I'm trying to get in to tabletop rpg games. I'm very new and the people that want to play with me are also very new. After some googling I stumbled on the D&D red box. This looked as a great way to learn d&d. (I was doubting about between d&d and pathfinder, went with the first because of the name and the assumption it would be "more supported").

I also read there was a nice path from the redbox, to the dm kit etc etc. Though now I find out the dm kit is still available, it is very expensive. (a bit too for me). My big question is, what is the way to continue now after the redbox (except for paying tons of money). Hope someone can give me some hints and tips.

Patrick

Comment: Also relevant (but not a duplicate): [Where do I go from the Red box?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/27459/1204)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you're coming into D&D at a weird time when they're in between editions - it's like coming into a computer OS when they're winding down the current version but gearing up for another...luckily, you're never actually forced to upgrade at any point once you get what you need to play.

The good news is that some of this is available as PDFs via rpg.now at reasonable prices:

[DM's Kit - $20](http://www.rpgnow.com/product/121978/Dungeon-Masters-Kit-%284e%29)

[Rules Compendium - $12](http://www.rpgnow.com/product/121306/D&D-Rules-Compendium-%284e%29)

The other books you can probably get at not-outrageous prices via the usual choice of used book websites or at used bookstores.  Local used bookstores near colleges and universities tend to get more rpg books on a regular basis, and since Wizards of the Coast is gearing down 4E for the next edition, you can find a lot of 4E books for pretty cheap.