# DnD 4e Books to get (errata? where to get?)

Tags: dnd-4e

I have the DnD 4e red box, and some friends and I are keen to play more.

I live in Belgium (Europe) and finding your gear here isn't all that easy. Most of the books sold online come from America.

Which books should I get? First I thought I'd get the 3 core rulebooks, but now I see that there's alot (even game changing) errata. I also notice that there are different ways to get all your rules, some speak of buying 2 essential books and the compendium... I want to play the game, with quite some content, what is the way to go? Anyone that can point me out a good site that has these things for me?

(Then I also noticed that there are things like Players Handbook 2 etc. These are not updated version but expansions I presume?)

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is primarily a duplicate of [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27459/where-do-i-go-from-the-red-box)

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton I feel like this isn't an exact duplicate, because it asks other things like how to distinguish between expansion material and errata, where to find errata and so on. I agree that each question should be made indipendently and most are probably already here in our search engine.

Comment: @Jelle I suggest you to look at the question Brian linked. If you still have questions, look if they're somewhere on this site first. If not, please ask them separately. Start from Related questions in the sidebar ;)

Comment: I can change it to too broad if you'd like?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton no real need. I just wanted to be sure Jelle understood why, even if s/he thinks the question isn't a duplicate, it's not a good question for our format anyway.